$|\det(A)|=\Pi_{i=1}^n ||\vec{A}_i||\iff A$ has zero columns or $\{\vec{A}_1,\vec{A}_2,...,\vec{A}_n\}$ is an orthogonal set.
Suppose $A\in \mathbb C^{n,n}.$ Let $\vec{A}_1,\vec{A}_2,...,\vec{A}_n$ are the columns of $A.$ Then $|\det(A)|=\Pi_{i=1}^n ||\vec{A}_i||\iff A$ has zero columns or  $\{\vec{A}_1,\vec{A}_2,...,\vec{A}_n\}$ is an orthogonal set.
My attempt:-
Suppose $A$ has zero columns. Then statement is trivial.
Suppose $\{\vec{A}_1,\vec{A}_2,...,\vec{A}_n\}$ is an orthogonal set.
We know that every matrix has $QR$ decomposition. So, $A$ can be written as the product of unitary matrix $Q$ and an upper triangular matrix $R.$
That is $$A=QR$$ and $$R=Q^HA$$
$|\det(A)|=|\det(Q)\det R|=|\Pi_{i=1}^n R_{ii}|$
I also know that $\langle \vec R_i, \vec R_j \rangle=\langle Q^H\vec{A_i}, Q^H\vec{A_j} \rangle=\langle \vec{A_i}, QQ^H\vec{A_j} \rangle=\langle \vec{A_i}, \vec{A_j} \rangle.$ This show that $R$ is also orthogonal. $R$ is upper triangular. Hence, $R$ must be diagonal. Hence, $|\det(A)|=\Pi_{i=1}^n ||\vec{A}_i||.$
Suppose $|\det(A)|=\Pi_{i=1}^n ||\vec{A}_i||$
Case 1
$|\det(A)|=0$
Then $\Pi_{i=1}^n ||\vec{A}_i||=0$
$\exists k\in \{1,2,3,...,n\}:||\vec{A}_k||=0\iff \vec{A}_k=\vec{0}. $
Suppose
$|\det(A)|\neq 0$
$|\det(A)|^2=|\det(R)|^2=\Pi_{i=1}^n ||\vec{A}_i||^2=\Pi_{i=1}^n ||\vec{R}_i||^2$(Since from $QR$ decomposition)
I don't know how to proceed. Please help me.
Thank you

Side note: Use \Vert or \| for norm signs, that looks better than || – compare $| A |$ and $|| A ||$.

And use \prod for the product, not \Pi.

this is the equality case of Hadamard's determinant inequality which has been proven many times on this site

Each column of $R$ shows how you write the corresponding column of $A$ as a linear combination of columns in $Q$.
That is, $\vec{A}_j = R_{1j} \vec{Q}_1 + \dotsb + R_{nj} \vec{Q}_n$. Since $\vec{Q}_j$ are orthonormal, $\Vert\vec{A}_j\Vert^2 = \|R_{1j}\|^2 + \dotsb + \|R_{1j}\|^2$.
If $R$ is not diagonal, then $\|R_{jj}\| < \Vert\vec{A}_j\Vert$ for some $j$.
But since $R$ is triangular, its determinant is the product of the diagonal entries. Therefore,
$$\|\mathrm{det}(R)\| < \prod \Vert\vec{A}_j\Vert.$$

If $0 \ne |\det(R)|=\prod_{i=1}^n \|\vec{R}_i\|$ with an upper triangular matrix $R$ then $R$ is necessarily a diagonal matrix: The left-hand side is the product of the absolute values of the diagonal elements $R_{i, i}$ of $R$, so that necessarily $\|\vec{R}_i\| = |R_{i, i}|$ for all $i$, which means that $R_{i, i}$ is the only non-zero entry in $\vec{R}_i$.
It follows that $A = QR$ has pairwise orthogonal columns.
